# Password for guest

Tags: grubrescue

While I'm trying to repair grub using a live cd when I use sudo command it asks for password
But there is no password and if just hit enters it shows please try again
Is there any default password ?

Comment: Try `ubuntu`, that's often the default password.  If that doesn't work, run `whoami` and edit your question with that output.

Comment: Ubuntu LiveCD does NOT ask for a password. Which version of Ubuntu are you using?